# Using factories in AngularUI Route?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm writing an Ionic app, which uses AngularUI's Router. I'd like to query `localstorage` using a factory I wrote, so I can determine whether to show a first-run screen or not.

My index.html loads scripts in this order:

```
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
```

And my routes config looks like this (truncated for brevity):

```
angular.module('app.routes', [])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, storageFactory) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('myApp.mainscreen', {
    url: '/main',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

// ...

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/menu/main')
```

Now I have a module called `app.services`, which contains my factory, `storageFactory` (I know, I'm going to move it out of the services module ;)). When I attempt to inject storageFactory like so:

```
angular.module('app.routes', ['app.services', 'storageFactory'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, storageFactory) {
```

I get an error similar to this:

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'storageFactory' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I'm certain that my app has loaded app.services and storageFactory prior to loading, but I just can't seem to get it to work correctly.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: services aren't available yet when config runs. You can inject into a state  resolve though. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'd like to check for a value in `localstorage` called `firstrun`. If it's not set, show a "Welcome to my app" screen. If it is set, proceed to the main screen.

Comment: Use a resolve then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject factories in UI router resolve blocks, without injecting them in the config block since it can only be injected with providers. For example:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('myApp.mainscreen', {
    url: '/main',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      firstRun: ['storageFactory', function(storageFactory) {
        // Do what you want with storageFactory here!
        // Full infos here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve
      }]
    }
})
```

Comment: Your answer, and @charlietfl's hint about services not being avaialble when config runs gave me the answer I was looking for. Now my app displays a nice tutorial before beginning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you cant inject services in config only provides but you can do it in app.run Here's the calling order:

1. app.config() //only provides can be injected
2. app.run()
3. directive's compile functions (if they are found in the dom)
4. app.controller()
5. directive's link functions (again, if found)

in your case you can also use route resolve property